# Локализация предметов в игре, созданных через ScriptableObjects

Tags: c#, unity3d

Назрел вопрос по локализации игры. Для перевода использую встроенный ассет Localization. И все бы хорошо, но когда я дошел до переводов текста для предметов инвентаря, которые созданы через ScriptableObject's, возникла проблема - к созданному предмету невозможно добавить компонент необходимый для локализации, да и у предмета может быть несколько текстов: имя, описание и т.д. - как с этим то быть? Знаю, что можно доставать переводы по ключам, но как именно тогда это делать, если скрипт для создания предметов один, а предметов может быть в игре миллион и под каждый нужен свой перевод? Вот такая вот задачка.. Буду рад любым идеям и подсказкам ))

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, локализация не в зоне ответственности модели предмета, он может содержать только ключи. То что у предмета есть текст на каком-то там языке это головняк UI который его отображает.

Вот например у тебя есть `enum WeaponType { sword, knife, hammer, bow, crossbow, staff }`, ты же не будешь удивляться, что `WeaponType` не сможет выдать локализованный текст? `Item : ScriptableObject` это тоже самое! Есть объект с данными, локализация и UI, который использует данные для получения текста из локализации.

Миллион? Будь это миллион ты бы и один язык не потянул, куда уж там локализация на нескольких ))